# Changing Duplicate Values Within Subjects: R

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, tidyr, data-cleaning

My data looks like this:

| Country | GDP | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 1972 |
| A | 15 | 1973 |
| A | 20 | 1973 |
| A | 18 | 1975 |
| B | 25 | 1950 |
| B | 30 | 1951 |
| B | 35 | 1951 |
| B | 36 | 1953 |

I have so many observations look like data that I presented above. I want to change the duplicated years. However, I want to change first duplicated row of the year variable. I want to see my data like this:

| Country | GDP | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 1972 |
| A | 20 | 1973 |
| A | 15 | 1974 |
| A | 18 | 1975 |
| B | 25 | 1950 |
| B | 35 | 1951 |
| B | 30 | 1952 |
| B | 36 | 1953 |

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible option with `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Country, Year) %>%
  mutate(dup = case_when(n() == 1 ~ FALSE,
                         min(GDP) == GDP ~ TRUE,
                         TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>% 
  mutate(Year = ifelse(dup == TRUE, Year + 1, Year)) %>% 
  arrange(Country, Year) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-dup)
```

**Output**

```
  Country   GDP  Year
  <chr>   <int> <dbl>
1 A          10  1972
2 A          20  1973
3 A          15  1974
4 A          18  1975
5 B          25  1950
6 B          35  1951
7 B          30  1952
8 B          36  1953
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(Country, Year) %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  mutate(Year = min(Year) + row_number() - 1) %>%
  ungroup

#  Country   GDP  Year
#  <chr>   <int> <dbl>
#1 A          10  1972
#2 A          15  1973
#3 A          20  1974
#4 A          18  1975
#5 B          25  1950
#6 B          30  1951
#7 B          35  1952
#8 B          36  1953
```

This increments every `Year` by 1 starting from minimum value in each `Country`.

Comment: This is not what I want. I want to change first row of year. For instance, if first row of year is B 30 1951, I want to see this in dataset as B 30 1952. Thank you for reply!